# How to fully unfocus TextField in flutter without focus coming back later

Tags: android, flutter, focus, textfield

In my flutter app, I have a textfield that I want to be able to remove focus from by tapping a non-interactable component. This is not the default behaviour of textfields in flutter, so I need to find a way to manually do it. I've got it somewhat working by following the steps at https://flutterigniter.com/dismiss-keyboard-form-lose-focus/ and various other pages, which involves a GestureDetector at the root with an onTap that looks something like this:

```
onTap: () {
  FocusScopeNode cf = FocusScope.of(context);
  if (!cf.hasPrimaryFocus && cf.focusedChild != null) {
    cf.focusedChild.unfocus();
    cf.unfocus();
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I select the text field, click somewhere else (focus appears to disappear at this point), open a time picker, and close that time picker, the textfield is focused again. If I unfocus the textfield by clicking the "done" button on the keyboard instead, then opening/closing a time picker won't refocus the textfield, so I know it has to be a problem with the way I'm unfocusing it. What's the correct way of unfocusing it so focus won't come back like that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I figured it out, it looks like I needed to use `onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus()` in the GestureDetector at the root. I'm pretty sure that's the best solution to this particular problem, though I'm not sure if it can cause side effects.

Comment: unfocus works for me, but the GestureDetector will only catch it if nothing else catches the tap. So any other buttons on the screen have to also call unfocus.

Comment: @spekary Did you solve the issue mentioned in the comment above?

Answer (score 9):

wrap your whole screen to `GestureDetector`
there are two ways to dismiss the keyboard\

1. `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());`
2. 

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
```

so please try you code with this

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
onTap(){
    SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
   }
```

Comment: I'd already tried `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());`, it still has the same problem where the focus comes back after I open the time picker. The SystemChannels method didn't fix it either, it just hides the keyboard without removing focus, and then the keyboard comes back when I open the time picker.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me without the need to call the `unfocus` method is that I tell TextField itself not to request focus on its own.
In the text field itself I added:

```
focusNode: FocusNode(canRequestFocus: false),
```

I believe this is the correct way to handle that.

Comment: `FocusNode` must be created as a state variable and must be properly disposed.